# handle 50 EditText fields in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

I would like to create an Android application which contains nearly 50 edittext fieds.The data entered in the edittext fields should me stored in sqllite when pressed a Submit button and should retrive the data stored in sqllite when pressed Retrive button.

Now i am not understanding,how to handle 50 EditText fields in the above senerio?

Comment: You should create such amount of EditText boxes programmatically in a loop and hold their references in an array for e.g. `EditText[]`

Answer (score 1):

you should add EditText programmatically and set id for each editText is better way.

```
for(int i=0;i<50;i++){

     EditText et = new EditText(this);
     et.setId(i);  
     layout.addView(et,params);
}
```

- Get text from all editText using id of EditText.and add in sqlite.and `also set id in sqlite using id of edittext and retrieve value from sqlite using id of edittext.`